# disqus doesnt work on https pages in chrome. Any fix?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pug, disqus

i have an `https` page where i embed `disqus` for commenting on the posted data. Issue is when the page gets loaded in `chrome`, it blocks the `disqus code` to execute, as it is served from a `http` host.
specifically:

```
script(type="text/javascript")
var disqus_shortname = 'postocks';
(function() {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
})();
```

so disqus doesn't get loaded in chrome. Works fine in firefox,safari.

I tired to fix it by:

1. making dsq.src to
   `dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';` and it dint work.
2. i had seen the jquery docs section making use of the same earlier. Tried the page now sothat i could refer the code. Disqus seems removed.

Is there any fix by which i can geet it working on the https page?
Also if i get the embed.js on my https host and serve it, will that make a difference.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, load the Disqus content using `https`, as discussed [here](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/542119-can-disqus-be-loaded-via-https-).

```
dsq.src = 'https://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
```